# any way to synchronously open window in javascript and use dom?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to call window.open, create a window, and synchronously create elements in that page? Earlier questions from 3 years ago showed an asynchronous model where the javascript called in that page when the window load was completed.

The following code does not work when called from an html page.  Is that because the code is wrong, or is this impossible?

```
var w = null;
var quiz = null;

function mkdiv(parent, className) {
    var div = w.document.createElement(className);
    div.className = className;
    return div;
}

function getNextQC() {
    w = window.open('', 'test', 'width=800,height=600');
    if (!quiz)
    quiz = mkdiv("quiz");
    idnum = -1;
    quiz.style.backgroundColor="red";
    return mkdiv(quiz, "qc");
}

function addText(div, t) {
    var txt = w.document.createElement("p");
    txt.innerHTML = t;
    div.appendChild(txt)
}

function addTextInput(div, className, t) {
    var inp = w.document.createElement("input");
    inp.className = className;
    inp.value = t;
    div.appendChild(inp);
}

function fillin() {
    var div = getNextQC();
    addText(div, "What is 2 + 2?");
    addTextInput(div, "fillin", "");
}
```

Comment: Even if you could modify a page that hasn't loaded yet, the code you have there still wouldn't do anything. Nothing you have there is modifying the newly opened window. And why do you need to do this synchronously?